# Como fazer o ORDER BY DESC funcionar no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta na minha tabela usando o OREDER BY DESC, mesmo usando a [sintaxe correta](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) recebo o erro: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY IDADE DESC' at line 5".

A tabela que estou usando como exemplo é essa:

```
CREATE TABLE PESSOA
    (`nome` varchar(8), `idade` int, `estado_nascimento` varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO PESSOA
    (`nome`, `idade`, `estado_nascimento`)
VALUES
    ('joao', 12, 'sp'),
    ('maria', 26, 'rj'),
    ('joao', 15, 'mg'),
    ('fernanda', 30, 'ce')
;
```

E a consulta que estou fazendo é essa:

```
SELECT NOME
FROM PESSOA
WHERE ESTADO_NASCIMENTO NOT IN ('CE')
LIMIT 1
ORDER BY IDADE DESC;
```

Segue o link do SQL Fiddle com a tabela e a consulta para maior comodidade: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caf268/1

Alguém saberia dizer o que estou errando?

P.S.: Estou usando MySQL 5.6

Comment: Tem que excluir essa pergunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É necessário que mova o "LIMIT 1" para o *final* da query.

**Segue um exemplo do W3 School :**
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_limit

**SQL:**

```
SELECT NOME FROM PESSOA WHERE ESTADO_NASCIMENTO NOT IN ('CE') ORDER BY IDADE DESC LIMIT 1;
```

segue o **link** com o resultado da query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caf268/4